# Finding if an array of positive integers form a closed polygon

Tags: java

I have an array of non-negative integers, what I need to find if they form a closed polygon or not. (Order of elements does not matter)

Elements of array represents side length.

After breaking the problem I came upon the following solution.

Let n denote the length of an array.

- For n=3:- I need to check if 3 elements form a triangle. (DONE)
- For n=even number greater than 3:- I need to check if all the elements have at least one equal pair. (DONE)

E.g  arr={2,3,4,4,3,2}:- it will form a closed polygon.

- I am having a problem for rest of the values of n.

Please help me.
If there is some other optimized solution please do tell.

Sorry, I think for n=even and greater than 3 my solution is wrong.

Comment: What do the elements in this array represent? Do they represent side lengths?

Comment: @LakshayGarg yes they represent side lengths

Comment: You may want to look at https://mathoverflow.net/a/96669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see: https://mathoverflow.net/a/96669

> A closed polygon with side lengths {r_1, r_2, ..., r_n} exists if and
>   only if
>
> r_i ≤ P/2     where P is the perimeter i.e. P = r_1 + r_2 + ... + r_n for all i in {1..n}

Comment: Thanks, so I need two loops one for addition and other for checking.

Comment: Yes, that would be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Heres is are two java implementations of the algorithms shown in **[@LakshayGarg's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3033441/lakshay-garg)** answer and the linked [**mathoverflow question**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/96669):

```
public static boolean checkValidClosedPolygon1(int[] lineLengths) {
  int maxLineLength = Arrays.stream(lineLengths).max().getAsInt();
  int halfOfsum = IntStream.of(lineLengths).sum() / 2;
  return maxLineLength < halfOfsum;
}

public static boolean checkValidClosedPolygon2(int[] lineLengths) {
  int maxLineLength = Arrays.stream(lineLengths).max().getAsInt();
  int sumMinusMax = IntStream.of(lineLengths).sum() - maxLineLength;
  return maxLineLength < sumMinusMax;
}
```